# Can a device that support Kernel 4.1, work with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: usb

Please,I'd like to know if a usb wifi dongle(Edimax EW-7811UTC), that support kernel 2.6.18-4.1,can work with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.Thank you

Comment: The Linux kernel supports a wide variety of hardware...but also drops support too. We are not psychic - we need to know the exact model of hardware, and everything you can tell us about it to give you a clear, trustworthy answer.

Comment: I'm sorry,the usb wifi adapter is:Edimax EW-7811UTC.Thank you

Comment: Did try this howto here ? It is from 2014. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228244

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry "Pilot6",I accidentally broken the device.So I need few days to buy and receive another one.I forget to say,I have a Acer Aspire One AOA150/ZG5-32 bit.Can it work with this new dongle?What do you suggest to me to do?Buy another one or  leave it as it is?Thank you and sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there are people who update vendor drivers for new Linux kernels. Vendors do not bother in many cases.

So this device will work with the help of customized drivers you can find in github or PPAs.

Comment: Thank you "Pilot6" for your answer.But,I'm less than a beginner.This mean that with his driver it(Edimax EW-7811UTC) doesn't work because Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has kernel 4.4?but,unfortunately, I'm not able to find and install customized drivers from Github or PPAs.So,can you,please,help me.Thank you